# File upload 302?

Tags: javascript, php, web, cpanel

I've finally gotten my asynchronous file upload working, except it only seems to handle text files.

If I upload a text file, it works and saves the file. If I upload an image, it fails firebug reports the response has a 302 status, and I get sent to the root directory of my public_html

I thought it may be related to file size, but doesn't seem to be the case, as I made the text file larger than the image, and it worked out.

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting, I'll place the PHP relevant snippet below.

**PHP**

```
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']:false);
echo $fn;

try{
    file_put_contents("upload/".$fn, file_get_contents("php://input"));
    //echo file_get_contents("upload/".$fn);
}catch(exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**JS**

```
function UploadFile(file){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //on the below if
    //xhr.upload: returns a XMLHttpRequestUpload Object, I believe just to check if it's supported in broswer
    if (xhr.upload){
        xhr.open("POST","http://domain.com/absolutepath/what.php",true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-FILENAME",file.name);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4){
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(file);
    }else{
        alert("Sorry, don't think this is supported in your browser.");
    }
}
```

Is there a request header I should be setting? Is it something in php.ini I need to change? My max post size is I think 32MB, not sure what else would effect this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Files uploader return error 302](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029743/files-uploader-return-error-302)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`302` is a status code, not a error code. It means that server is redirecting you to another page. But with status OK and Found.

The problem is usually caused by server having `mod-security` turned on and the filter engine filtering uploads.

To get around this add this code to your `.htaccess` file for your hosting account, if you are a client, or edit in apache configuration if you are administrator:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You might be on the right path.Changing it on my hosting account didn't change anything, I'll go back to my web host and see if they can assist. Is there more I can read up about?

Comment: Yes, search about mod_security with upload error. There are tons of articles on Google. Try in your localhost to test the turning off.  Good luck!